# Three.js - How to create smoke with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, particles, smoke

I want to create brown smoke blowing up in the sky.

How can I create this?

Comment: Can you provide a picture showing what the end result might look like?

Comment: check with three.js.

Comment: [this](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particles.html) example can be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ShaderParticleEngine](http://squarefeet.github.io/ShaderParticleEngine/) received a rewrite for `three.js-r72` with **heavy** API changes, so I am updating this answer. See this Answers history for a comparison and/or settings for `ShaderParticleEngine 0.8` / `three.js-r71`.

---

It now allows the user to fine tune even more parameters, so you could create this beautiful twisted smoke:

[image: smoke blowing from crash site]

Example Settings for the Emitter in the Screenshot:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
var url = 'assets/images/particles/cloudSml.png';
var texture = loader.load( url );

var particleGroupCrash = new SPE.Group({
    texture: {
        value: texture
    },
    blending: THREE.NormalBlending
});

var crashemitter = new SPE.Emitter({

    maxAge: { value: 12 },
    position: { 
        value: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
        spread: new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0.5, 2 ),
    },
    size: {
        value: [ 2, 8 ],
        spread: [ 0, 1, 2 ]
    },
    acceleration: {
        value: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
    },
    rotation: {
        axis: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ),
        spread: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 20, 0 ),
        angle: 100 * Math.PI / 180,
    },
    velocity: {
        value: new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, -0.5 ),
        spread: new THREE.Vector3( 0.25, 0.1, 0.25 )
    },
    opacity: {
        value: [ 0.2, 0.5, 0 ]
    },
    color: {
        value: [ new THREE.Color( 0x333333 ), new THREE.Color( 0x111111 ) ],
        spread: [ new THREE.Vector3( 0.2, 0.1, 0.1 ), new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ) ]
    },
    particleCount: 600,
});
```

Three.js r73

Comment: one point for the pic :) r72 also has a particle engine http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpu_particle_system

Comment: Haha thanks! The new particle plugin also looks nice, but its missing a good [documentation](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/6942#issue-98658102) and examples so far :-(

Comment: how do I now add this smoke to the scene? Do I  do scene.add(crashemitter) ?

Comment: ah like this: scene.add( particleGroupCrash.mesh );